# Recycleview item is not notify for focus item of recycle view on Screen

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have 50 or more item on Recycleview. OnScreen 10 Item is showing. 
I am updating my data in my ROOM Database in every 15 seconds. and after than I notify my recycleview adapter from latest  data from my local room.

I success fully notify item when recycle is scrolling.

But main problem is on screen item is not changing. its only changing when scroll recycle view.

Here is My Code

```
        mDataVehicle.clear();
        mDataVehicle.addAll(roomDB.getUpdatedVehicleList());
        if (mVehicleAdapter == null) {
            mVehicleAdapter = new VehicleAdapter(activity, mDataVehicle);
            recycleView.setAdapter(mVehicleAdapter);

        } else {
            mVehicleAdapter = new VehicleAdapter(activity, mDataVehicle);
            mVehicleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: In the else part why are you again initializing VehicleAdapter?

Comment: Why creating new Adapter in `else` ? Try setting up method in adapter to update your list.

Comment: this will send refreshed data to Adapter.So notifyDataSetChanged() work

Comment: No, when using `new` you're creating a new Adapter, not updating existing one. You're sending new adapter to your RecyclerView, that is you're "refreshing" View itself, not Adapter. At least you would be refreshing it if that new Adapter was attached to the view.

Comment: So How should I do? I just invalidate new value

Comment: Thanks to everyone That was problem. Now I'm Only using mVehicleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()